# Force CSS Transitions on iPad using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following [Demo](http://jsbin.com/adacot/1/edit) which works beautifully on my desktop. I hover the circle and it expands - yay!

However, the circle doesn't expand when tapping it on my iPad.

**Is it possible to use some jQuery to "trigger" the expand on a single click on my tablet?**

I am fairly new to jQuery so a little unsure where to begin. I'd rather not replace the `<div>` with an `<a>` hyperlink tag as in time I'll be adding hyperlinks inside the circle.

Would really appreciate help with this. Here is a copy of my CSS & HTML for reference:

**CSS:**

```
.containMe {
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index:5
}

.containMe {
    width: 147px; 
    height: 147px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 40px;
}

.circle {
    width: 147px; 
    height: 147px;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

    -webkit-border-radius: 75px;
    -moz-border-radius: 75px;
    border-radius: 75px;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

    .containMe:hover .circle {
        width: 285px; 
        height: 285px;

        -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
        -moz-border-radius: 150px;
        border-radius: 150px;
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="containMe">
  <div class="circle" style="background-color:#15c3a8">
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Many thanks for any help with this.

Comment: Well, tapping isn’t `:hover`. Try `:active`.

Comment: Hi ryanh. So, should I add an `active` state declaration to the `.circle` class?

Comment: `selector:active` could work! with jQuery you just bind an click event to the desired element like `$('.circle').on('touchstart',function(){});`

Comment: Cool, @codelio. Will try right now. Stay tuned :)

Comment: and of corse, this works also with native js because `touchstart` is the equivalent event of click at a desktop would be

Comment: That worked beautifully sir!!! Feel free to create an Answer with that and I'll green tick it good :-) Out of interest, what would the code be to allow click to close it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with css

```
selector:active { 
    /* gives css to an active element */
    /* so you could start in example webkit keyframes */ 
}
```

could work but much easier is to handle this with js or jquery!

with jQuery you just bind an click event to the desired element

```
$('.circle').on('touchstart',function(e){
   console.log(e); // e contains all needed information from your touch event
});
```

well sometime you want to produce a page for mobile and desktops, so you need something which changes your native js event names you are watching to.. 
you could do something like *(but you should proof this first line of code, i just testet it on Apple devices and Desktops)*

```
var touch=/Android|BlackBerry|iPhone|iPad|iPod|IEMobile/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
var multitouch=/iPod|iPhone|iPad/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
var ev= {
    down: !touch ? "mousedown" : "touchstart",
    keydown: !touch ? "keydown" : "keydown",
    move: !touch ? "mousemove" : "touchmove",
    up: !touch ? "mouseup" : "touchend",
    click: !touch ? "click" : "touchstart"
};
```

so you can access eventListener without to worry about different event names.
dont code twice! ^^ you would do this with variables like..

```
var elm=document.getElementById('idelement');
elm.addEventListener( ev.down, function(e){
    // console.log(e.target);
}, false);

//or in jQuery, depending on your given classname  
$('.circle').on(ev.down, function(e){
    /* do nice stuff with e.target or $(this) */
});
```

you can also do nice stuff with `gesturechange` events, but beware of this eventtype, it is not everywhere implemented the same.

Comment: What a thoroughly comprehensive answer. Can't thank you enough for going over this in such excellent detail. Out of interest, when 'active', if I were to click it again or another circle, how do I program it so it contracts?

Comment: that for you could use CSS `#selector:active { }` so you know which element is responsible, with class names logical all elements are reacting who have that className.

Comment: I've got it working great here: http://jsbin.com/adacot/6/edit Is it easy enough to add jQuery to "close" the circle on clicking an active one?

Comment: you want your circles to stay "open" if clicked and closed when clicked again?

Comment: If clicked when "open", they should close.

Comment: Almost perfect. Final change. Is it possible only ONE circle can be open at any one time?

Comment: yes this is possible, we say jQuery how to handle all the other before we start to "open" the touched one. http://jsbin.com/etucij/1/edit

Comment: Hmm. The hover now no longer works on the circles on desktop and clicking when open doesn't close :'(

Comment: yes not so diffcult. you can also see here how the class handling works with jquery http://jsbin.com/ocekak/1/edit